# How to print in the same line in AMPL

Tags: ampl

Good evening everyone! I have this silly question but I cannot find the solution in the language manual. It starts to seem that it is not possible. Until now I have tried using:

```
print "Write something";
print "This is not in the same line";
```

I know I can concatenate strings with `&` but that does not solve my use case. Does anyone know how to print in the same line in AMPL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
printf "Write something";
printf "This is in the same line";
printf "\nThis is a new line";
```

See [AMPL `printf` documentation](https://ampl.com/NEW/printf.html) for more detail on options. `print` is good for simple output statements, `printf` gives you more power to micro-manage how the output prints.

Comment: Life changer. The way to use it with variables is: `printf "Whatever %u", varname` just in case someone is looking at it. Thank you so much.